# Broadcasting Beacon-Frames with custom IE in Android 4.3 using AP Mode

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-source, wifi, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I am trying to add some custom Vendor Specific Elements for Beacon Frames in Android 4.3. I found following Informations in a Config File in `external/wpa_supplicant_8/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`  in the AOSP Source Code

> "Additional vendor specific elements for Beacon and Probe Response
>   frames This parameter can be used to add additional vendor specific
>   element(s) into the end of the Beacon and Probe Response frames. The
>   format for these element(s) is a hexdump of the raw information
>   elements (id+len+payload for one or more elements). This is used in AP
>   and P2P GO modes. ap_vendor_elements=dd0411223301"

I tried it that way but that didnt`t worked , do you have any idea how this could work? My goal is it to add this custom elements to the beacon frames send in AP mode.

Thx

Comment: When you enable apmode, it would be `hostapd` instead of wpa_supplicant.I think, There would be a `hostapd.conf`/`softap.conf` somewhere.

Comment: thank you for your answer. there is a `hostapd.conf` in `/external/wpa_supplicant_8/hostapd/` , i try to add the vendor_elements there, but i didnt work either , maybe the `Android.mk` doesn`t compile the `hostapd` correct ?

Comment: just make sure by renaming `/external/wpa_supplicant_8/hostapd` and turn on apmode, if it is still turning on means the location you are mentioned is incorrect.

Comment: that was a good advice, i removed the Makefile of hostapd from the Android.mk , compiled it and now i cant turn on AP-mode - so the source code in hostapd is definitely responsible for Ap-mode - i will try now to add the vendor elements there

Comment: ok, can you try hostapd.conf from /data/misc/wifi ?

Comment: the problem is , everytime i try to change the hostapd.conf on the phone it gets overwritten with the old settings, when i start the hotspot ... i think i have to start hostapd manually ( with adb shell) with another .conf  file

Comment: exactly, because when you turn on Tethering from device UI,It will replace with default .conf file. You can start hostapd from adb shell.

Comment: do you know how i can start hostapd from shell ? i tried it with `hostapd -B /data/misc/wifi/hostapd.conf`

Comment: before that, how did you make your wlan firmware up ?

Comment: i did it like you describe on my other post , i think this method works fine , but the problem is to start the hotspot